# How to centre and make responsive a row of divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://jsfiddle.net/raLmo8kd/

Hi I have a page and I want to make the squares appear in the middle of the page both vertically and horizontally. I have a container that I want roughly 80% of the page to leave 20% space either side. I was wondering how I can make this fully responsive for all browsers and devices.

#### HTML

```
<div class="splashcontainer">
    <h1 class="splashheader">Title</h1>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.splashcontainer{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

.splashheader{
text-align: center;
font-size: 62px;
font-family: font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.splashcontainer div{
width: 20%;
margin: 0px 2% 0 2%;
padding-bottom: 20%;
background-color: deepskyblue;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [vertical align](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) the box using 3 lines of CSS.

```
.splashcontainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Next make sure the `<html>` and `<body>` elements are 100% high.

Last, you need to take care of the spaces between the divs using `<!-- -->`.

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raLmo8kd/5/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="splashcontainer">
    <h1 class="splashheader">Title</h1>
    <div></div><!--
 --><div></div><!--
 --><div></div><!--
--><div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

.splashcontainer{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.splashheader{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-family: font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.splashcontainer div{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0px 2% 0 2%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a generated element , `vertical-align` and `display:inline-block;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/raLmo8kd/6/)

```
body:before , html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    text-align:center;
}
body:before {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.splashcontainer{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 80%;
    background:gray;
}

.splashheader{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-family: font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.splashcontainer div{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0px 2% 0 2%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

or `display:flex;`, `height`  and  `margin:auto;`

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/raLmo8kd/7/)**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    display:flex;
}

.splashcontainer{
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%;
    background:gray;
}

.splashheader{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-family: font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.splashcontainer div{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0px 2% 0 2%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
```

display: inline-block;
}